# Can I reduce app space by deleting unwanted files?

Tags: applications, sd-card, photos, customization, bloatware

Specifically, I'm an artist and use PicsArt photo studio a lot, which is a great app. The issue is that my phone is ALWAYS low on space (thanks a bunch, sprint bloatware!) So this app is awesome, but they add around 10 MB of extra crap like clipart, most of it stored on the SD card. I've googled this multiple times, but I've only come up with results like "how to delete apps" which are useless to answer my question. 
I'm scared to go around deleting things casually, so I'd love to hear if any of you Android enthusiasts have tried the type of app customization I'm proposing.

Comment: What do you mean by 'reduce app space'?  Yes, you can delete unwanted files and free up space on your memory card or internal memory.

Comment: @shanabus - I think they mean to delete some of the files from a particular app (the clip art files from the PicsArt app).  About the only answer I have for this is to make a backup of the files in question, delete the originals and see if the app still works or not.

Comment: Can't figure out how to reply directly, but yes, @Compro01, that's right, and I suppose I'll just take your advice and test it out after backing up the files. I guess I can always uninstall and reinstall if I screw the app itself up somehow ...

Comment: All apps store its data @ /sdcard/android/pacage name.  you can delete from there.